# Flex chart display with no datapoint

Tags: apache-flex, bar-chart, point

I need to display price of item for every date in the month.
The chart can be Bar chart or plot chart.

Question:

Suppose there is no data available for 01/15/2010 then,
Is there a way to display (01/15/2010) on x axis but no (bar or plot point) corresponding y axis point ?

i.e. there will be a empty space between 2 bars or plot points.

Currently I am using 0 , But 0 is a valid value.

Let me know if such a display is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

Here is the solution.
Say i want show the following data [jan, 10] [ feb , ]

**Step 1:**
To hide the point on the Barchart, send a NaN from server.
In the above example , it would mean [jan,10][Feb, **NaN**].
    --This causes an undesirable effect of showing the value near the title bar.

**Step 2:**
Now hide the data tip, Follow the solution at the link:
[flex chart hide a datatip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873258/flex-chart-hide-a-datatip)

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to use *some* kind of value for a plot or a bar or a column. If you use null, no space will be reserved for that data point.

For example, if you have three columns — say, March, April and May — and the values in the dataProvider are [3, null, 5], the April column will simply not show up and March and April will each get wider.

What you can do is create a dataTipFunction (see ChartBase) that tells the user no data is available if the datum is 0.

Comment: Thank you, I started looking into Chart Base, not much available.
Will try and figure out your solution.

Comment: I took the advice , but there is new issue.
The problem with this approach is that user has to mouse over to see the tip, Is there a way we can set "color" of individual plot series point based on the value ? My idea is to change it to some blue to say missing data. and green for good data.